# Recommended master games for teaching chess

Tags: beginner, database, teaching

I am teaching chess to beginners and am looking for recommended games to be discussed/analyzed together.

So the games should be relatively simple, short and ideally focus on one main theme (e.g. mating attack, weak squares,...
My main interest is to have very straightforward games, without complicated sidelines, etc. It is not necessary that the games are commented/annotated. It would be good if the games were ordered by theme.

It is essential that an electronic version (printable is fine) exists.

What are good resources for such games?

Comment: If I've understood this question correctly you're mostly interested in game suggestions, right? Because I think that in general once you know the games you want there should be no issue whatsoever to find them and compile them in suitable game collections on chessgames.com.

Comment: Correct. There are many beautiful games out there, but if I want to teach something about e.g. weak squares I prefer games that are mostly focused on this topic. So I am looking for (1) simple games and (2) games sorted by topic/theme.

Comment: One more question: are you mainly looking for entire games, or would you also appreciate suggestion for shorter game snippets illustrating certain concepts (like zugzwang in the endgame, where an entire game might be a drag to go through just to get to the main point)?

Comment: Yes, snippets would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get a copy of the old Chessmaster XI (or any version). It has a training section with Josh Waitzkin that I liked a lot. It has games sorted by theme.

I assume a google search for famous chess games will also give some good results.

Finally you’re asking a bit for teachers to give you the results of their hard work, giving a bunch of games, presorted for you per theme. It would’ve been nice if you shared in return, e.g. a link to your personal website where you’ve got a (small) database of games you’ve already found and sorted yourself and which you’ll update with answers from this post.

Comment: I also saw joshua Waitzkin lectures way way back and i loved them. I watched them more than once and i would definitely recommend them as well. The most recent versions of Chessmaster have some new lectures that the old ones didn't have, but the difference in the amount of lectures is considerably small.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Morphy vs Duke Karl / Count Isouard(Opening Principles, Initiative, Basic Tactics)
PGN:

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7
8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8
13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8# 1-0

Kivanc Haznedaroglu vs Jamshed Isaev(King Side Attack, Basic Tactics)
PGN:

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Bxc6 dxc6 5. O-O Bg4 6. h3 h5 7. d3 Qf6 8. Nbd2 Ne7 9. Re1 Ng6 10. d4 Bd6 11. c3 O-O-O 12. Qe2 exd4 13. e5 Bxe5 14. hxg4 hxg4 15. Nxe5 Nxe5 16. Qxe5 Qh4 17. Kf1 d3 18. f3 g3 19. Qf5+ Kb8 20. Qc5 Rd4 21. Qxd4 Qxd4 22. Re8+ Ka7 0-1

Jose Raul Capablanca vs Marc Fonaroff(Pawn Weakness, Backrank, Fork) 
PGN:

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 d6 4. Nc3 Nf6 5. Bb5 Bd7 6. O-O Be7 7. Re1 exd4 8. Nxd4 Nxd4 9. Qxd4 Bxb5 10. Nxb5 O-O 11. Qc3 c6 12. Nd4 Nd7 13. Nf5 Bf6 14. Qg3 Ne5 15. Bf4 Qc7 16. Rad1 Rad8 17. Rxd6 Rxd6 18. Bxe5 Rd1 19. Rxd1 Bxe5 20. Nh6+ Kh8 21. Qxe5 Qxe5 22. Nxf7+ 1-0

Rudolf Rezso Charousek vs Jakob Wollner(Inititive, Mating Attack)
PGN:

1.e4 e5 2.d4 exd4 3.c3 dxc3 4.Bc4 Nf6 5.Nf3 Bc5 6.Nxc3 d6 7.O-O O-O 8.Ng5 h6 9.Nxf7 Rxf7 10.e5 Ng4 11.e6 Qh4 12.exf7+ Kf8 13.Bf4 Nxf2 14.Qe2 Ng4+ 15.Kh1 Bd7 16.Rae1 Nc6 17.Qe8+ Rxe8 18.fxe8=Q+ Bxe8 19.Bd6# 1-0